# How do I make an image unclickable where the background is transparent?

Tags: vb.net, image, visual-studio-2010, button, shapes

I want to do an app where parts of the human body act like buttons but I need them to only shot the event when it clicks on the image not around it.
If I do it with an image with transparent background and I click on the back it shots the event anyway.

Comment: What language / frameworks are you wanting to use? I'm assuming that you're going to be using C# since you put VS2010 as a tag?

Comment: im using visual basic 2010 .net

Comment: Winforms? WebForms? WPF? MVC?

Comment: You need to do hit testing to find out what was clicked.  Bitmap.GetPixel() will tell you.  If you also need to identify the body parts then the standard trick is to use *two* bitmaps.  One that the user looks at and another that uses a specific color for each part.

Comment: i m using winforms thanks for the tip ill try with de getpixel function

Comment: im trying to use the mouseposition method of the picturebox to get the position i want to test with getpixel but it isnt calibrated with the bitmap. when i click in the area it doesnt corresponds with the bitmap im new at this so im sorry if this is a little basic

Comment: Thanks for your answers ive found the solution